# is the product of two symmetric positive definit matrices symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the product of two symmetric positive definit matrices $A$, $B$ always a symmetric matrix?

Comment: As various people have explained in the answers, it is not. $B^TAB$ is, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a counterexample:
$$ A = \pmatrix{ 1 & 2\cr 2 & 5\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 2\cr},\ 
AB = \pmatrix{-1 & 3\cr -3 & 8\cr}.$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, the product of two symmetric matrices $A= A^T$ and $B = B^T$ is symmetric if and only if they commute, that is, if and only if

$AB = BA; \tag 1$

to see this, suppose that (1) binds; then

$(AB)^T = B^TA^T = BA = AB; \tag 2$

and likewise, if

$(AB)^T = AB, \tag 3$

we have

$AB = (AB)^T = B^TA^T = BA. \tag 4$

Thus we may find plenty of counterexamples by simply choosing $A$ and $B$ such that

$AB \ne BA; \tag 5$

I leave it to my myriad of readers to find specific examples; it is not difficult.

In closing, we observe that positive definiteness plays no role here.